# How to unwrap a JSON column and split the attributes into seperate columns with live streaming data

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, amazon-dynamodb

[image: DATASET]

[image: ERROR]

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
split = df['device_data'].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(json.loads(x)))

a = df.drop(columns=['device_data'])
b = pd.concat(list(split), ignore_index=True)
df = a.join(b)
```

This is the code I am attempting to run. It works when I run a csv file but I am continuously streaming data from DyanmoDB and this code will not work and I receive the following error when attempting to do so.

[image: FULL CODE]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it already contains dict then it should be easier to work :

```
a = [{'temperature':20,'humidity':30,'pressure':180},{'temperature':30,'humidity':90,'pressure':120}] 

data = pd.DataFrame()

data["new"] = a

split = data["new"].apply(pd.Series)

temperature |   humidity |  pressure
0   20  30  180
1   30  90  120
```

Therefore i think your code should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
split = df['device_data'].apply(pd.Series)

df =  pd.concat([df.drop(columns=['device_data']),split],axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, this did exactly what I needed it to do, thank you